# Vagrant installation issue - unmet dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, installation, vagrant

I am trying to install vagrant on Ubuntu desktop 18.04.2 and I am getting the following error

```
sudo apt install vagrant
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vagrant : Depends: ruby-net-scp (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: ruby-net-sftp but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: ruby-net-ssh (>= 1:2.6.6) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: vagrant-libvirt but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How to fix this? Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

The command to have Ubuntu fix unmet dependencies and broken packages is

```
~ sudo apt-get install -f
```

Ubuntu will try to fix itself when you run the command. When it completes, you can test if it worked by running the command again.

Comment: What is the msg?

Comment: No message. Nothing at all.

Comment: One possible cause of unmet dependencies could be corrupted package database, and/or some packages weren’t installed properly. To fix this problem, open terminal and try to run one of the following commands:

~ sudo apt-get clean
or,
~ sudo apt-get autoclean. I hope we will fix it today :)

Comment: Can you please check if all the Ubuntu Repositories are enabled ?